# My async component renders two times and expect doesn't wait for the second time even using await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, jestjs, react-testing-library

I wanna test a simple app that takes a code from an input and then shows the code in the document.

My component renders two times: one without input value (I init `useState` as `undefined`); and another one with with the correct string. I want my test to wait for the second time and the code to appear. Right now fails on the first render.

This is my test:

```js
test("Keeps track of input value [async]", async () => {
  const { getByText, queryByText, getByLabelText, debug } = render(<App />);
  userEvent.type(getByLabelText("Code:"), "12345")
  userEvent.click(getByText(/Change route/i));
  expect(await queryByText(/The code you chose is: 12345/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This is my app code:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [route, setRoute] = useState("home")
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  return (
    <Router
      currentRoute={route}
      render={(currentRoute: string) => (
        <Fragment>
          <Router.View route="home" currentRoute={currentRoute}>
            This is the homepage.
            <label htmlFor="code">Code:</label><input id="code" type="text" value={code} onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => {
              setRoute('selection')
            }}>Change route</button>
          </Router.View>
          <Router.View route="selection" currentRoute={currentRoute}>
            <Selection code={code} />
          </Router.View>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Selection code (`Promise.resolve` to mock async):

edit: It turns out `useEffect` isn't even called on the first render

```js
const Selection = (props) => {
  const [code, setCode] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve(props.code).then(res => setCode("12345"));
  },[props.code])
  return (<>This is the selection page. The code you chose is: {code}</>)
}
```

Made a codesandbox but it fails for unrelated reasons. Will update if I can get it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-thunder-z9oqq

Comment: Maybe:
`const result = await queryByText(/The code you chose is: 12345/i);
expect( result ).toBeInTheDocument();`

Comment: Didn't work. Still get `<div>This is the selection page. The code you chose is:</div>` from `screen.debug()`

Comment: *It turns out useEffect isn't even called on the first render* - yes, it doesn't, it's called when a component is mounted. Also `await queryByText` doesn't make sense because it doesn't return a promise. If you didn't get a specific moment to wait, use `waitFor`.

Answer (score 0):

This test solved my problem:

```js
test("Keeps track of input value [async]", async () => {
  render(<App />);
  userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Code:/i), "12345")
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Change route/i));
  expect(await screen.findByText(/12345/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Digging around I came to the conclusion that I should `screen.findByText()` to `await` an element to appear. `queryBy*` should be used mostly for asserting dissapearance according to [Kent C Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library/)